# Improving Performance Of Query To Run In Less Than 1 ms / Record

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I am writing an application in .NET and SQL Server 2008. I am using the express edition.

I have a database table with an VARCHAR primary key. The table has approx 10 million records.

Id : VARCHAR(76), primary key, clustered index on this column

HitDice : VARCHAR(83)

There is a simple query which I run on this table

```
SELECT HitDice from TABLE WHERE Id = @Id;
```

I have taken an average time over the query execution time and found that the query takes about 8 ms to retrieve a record.

While this may be fast enough for many applications, It is too slow for me (see my additional notes for reasons on why this is too slow). I need to bring it down by an order of magnitude.

I have tried to create a computed column that hashes the VARCHAR primary key and index that instead. I found that suggestion here http://csliu.com/2007/07/hash-index-in-microsoft-sql-server.

I have also tried to change the query to return multiple records instead of 1 record at a time.

My new table looks like this:

Id : VARCHAR(76), primary key

HitDice : VARCHAR(83)

IdHash : Int, computed column = CHECKSUM(Id), non-clustered index on this column

And my query now looks something like this:

```
SELECT Id,HitDice from dbo.BlotExposures WHERE IdHash IN (CHECKSUM(@Id1),CHECKSUM(@Id2),CHECKSUM(@Id3),...,CHECKSUM(@Idn)) AND Id IN (@Id1,@Id2,...,@Idn);
```

This approach had a slightly better execution to the previous query, around 7 ms / record.

Seeing as I do not have much database experience, one of my problems is that I do not know whether my current execution times are reasonable or not. Is it reasonable to get the query to perform in < 1ms / record?

If yes, what should I do? Do I need better hardware? Or is there something else I can try?

Some additional notes:

1. I have profiled the application and found that about 40% time us used executing this query. Therefore, I am sure this is the bottleneck.
2. I am using memory caching, but the problem is that records are not usually retrieved multiple times in any reasonable amount of time. Although I haven't done too much analysis on this, I estimate that only 30% of my cached items are ever reused.
3. To give some context on why I am saying this query is too slow. I am programming a neural network that learns to play backgammon. Each turn, the query needs to be run multiple times and hundred of thousands of games need to be played for the neural network to learn. Lets assume I need 50 records per turn and there are 40 turns per game. At 8 ms / record and 100 000 games that's 18 days to complete. If I manage to bring the query down to approx 1 ms, that's 2 days. A huge saving.
4. Execution plans. The first queries execution plan is very simple. Cost 100% on a clustered index seek. The second query uses 50% cost on a non-clustered index seek and 50% on a RID lookup.

EDIT:

As requested I am adding url with the execution plan for an instance of the first query. It took 73 ms to run. Please see http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2ko7kp&s=8#.U7HVSPmSzPo

Comment: Retrieving a single row from memory by seeking the clustered index should return in <1ms even with an inefficient string key. Post the actual execution plan. change your string columns to use a bin2 collation.

Comment: What size is the actual table? It might not all fit into the buffer cache with the 1GB express memory limitation. Especially if your express instance has other databases/tables competing for this space. As a ballpark `((76 + 83) * 10000000) /1024/1024/1024 = 1.5 GB` and that doesn't include extra row and page overhead but does assume that your varchars take full length.

Comment: @usr I have edited my question and added a link to an image that shows the actual execution plan for a particular query. I have never used bin2 and will look into this.

Comment: Martin's theory is quite appealing. You can test it like this: The first time you access a page it shoult take ~10ms for a disk seek. Next time you access that page it should take 0ms. Try this for a few rows that are on different pages (just use random ids and hope to be lucky).

Comment: FWIW [I see an elapsed time of `0 ms`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/w2seh.png) when setting up a test table of that description and seeking into those keys when all pages are in memory and no physical reads are required. You could look to see what wait types you are encountering (e.g. Disk IO, Network IO, locks)

Comment: From a Backgammon engine point of view - what is it you need to look up from a DB to evaluate a position? Is it a bear-off database?

Comment: @EbbeM.Pedersen the reason I am using a DB is because one of the features I am using is blot exposure (the probability that a blot can be hit = number of dice rolls that can hit any blot / 36). This is quite expensive to compute, so I wanted to store it in a database for fast retrieval.

Comment: @usr I can confirm this is the case. When running random queries I get multiple reads of between 10 - 30 ms and also multiple reads of 0 ms.

Comment: @MartinSmith the table is approx 1.5GB. Can you elaborate on your comment on wait types. How do I discover what wait types are encountered?

Comment: @Ofir Well in that case best case for you would be that 1/3 of your random reads need a physical IO. You could snapshot this DMV http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179984.aspx before and after your test for a rough idea if no other concurrent activity or use extended events to measure waits for a single session http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/capturing-wait-stats-for-a-single-operation/

Comment: @Ofir We are talking lookup-times in milliseconds. You can literately do million of instructions in 1 ms. I'm pretty sure blot exposure can be calculated faster than a look-up in a db.

Comment: Run more than one thread in the application layer.  Just because the database takes 2 ms for one read doesn't mean that only 500 reads happen a second.  This is the difference between throughput and latency.

Comment: @EbbeM.Pedersen I've struggled to do this so far. I just ran a test and it takes me on average 8 ms to compute blot exposure. It turns out to be an expensive operation. For each blot, you have to loop over the possible dice combo and then see if that dice combo can hit that blot. I use recursion here to go over all the possible moves and see if a hit occurs. I do various optimizations in the recursion (i.e. if you roll 4 1 and the blot is 6 points away you know you cannot hit, no need to apply recursion) but it is still expensive. I will look into it more and see if I can make it faster.

Comment: From any valid BG position there is an upper bound of possible positions you can reach from that with the next move. For each non double role there is at most 15 * 15 possible positions, and for each double there is at most 15 * 15 * 15 * 15 possible positions. With 6 double roles and 15 non doubles, that gives an upper bound of maximum 307125 possible moves. However, in actual play there are far less possible moves on each roll - properly less than a few thousand. If you calculate all possible moves, you also know all exposed hits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your database is stored on a conventional hard disk, then in the cases where you query records that aren't in memory (eg. your own cache, the database cache or the disk cache), it is bound to come from the disk. And this can only happen as fast as you can look it up on the disk. According to [this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive_performance_characteristics) the average seek time for most common desktop drives is typically around 9 ms. This seems to be in line with your observations.

The solution to this is to either

1. Place the database on a faster medium
2. Order the rows in a way that increases the effect of the disk cashing
3. Just put everything in memory - 10 million records of less than 200 bytes is less than 2 GB. Also, work on reducing the size of the key and the data. Is it BG positions you encode in the ID? Backgammon positions can be encoded in 10 bytes - look at [gnubg's encoding.](http://gnubg.org/documentation/doku.php?id=appendix#16)

Comment: Thanks Ebbe this is interesting. Point 3 is well worth looking into. I didn't know about the efficient encoding. Can you elaborate on point 2? What do you mean order the rows to increase the effect of disk caching?

Comment: Point2: Data are read in blocks, not in rows. If you have rows that are often access together then you would get a benefit of ordering the data so they are on the same block.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a lot of code based on this designed you might want to switch your database to MySql and use the memory table option. If you can afford the memory to do this, should run very fast. If you don't have the memory, suggest you get the memory.